# "but this is seriously ridiculous but i kind of knew that this might happen so now we fully understand we we stand with you guys!"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

While reading a comprehension i did go through a message sent by one person to another. The first person mentions:

> "but this is seriously ridiculous but i kind of knew that this might
>   happen so now we fully understand we we stand with you guys!"

Can anyone describe its meaning, all that i knew is this is written out of anger blaming for something wrong. Also I know that use of double "we" is also wrong.

Comment: The first *we* should be *where* as in *...where we stand with you guys*, unless the author deliberately wrote a mistake.

Comment: I see you made a new English structure which is 'but...but' so you have two buts?  just kidding. I try to paraphrase it: "this doesn't make sense, but I almost knew from the beginning that it could happen. Now that we completely understand what the situation is, we're going to support you"

Comment: @Azad "now I know where I stand with you" doesn't mean what you think it does. It means "I used to think we were working together and helping each other, but your recent actions have shown that you are only helping yourself and from now on I will be more careful about trusting you."

Comment: Yea, you're right. "I will be careful about trusting you" that's what it really means. Thanks ☺ guess that was 'stand by' which means support.

Comment: @Azad This is a better definition of the idiom 'to know where one stands' http://www.dictionary.com/browse/know-where-one-stands. You're correct that if  the sentence was "we stand with you guys!" it would mean 'we support you', but "understand/know where we stand" is different.

Comment: Aha then that's 'where' which changes the meaning. Got it.